# How to set a variable with both single and double quotes?

Tags: coldfusion, escaping

How do I set a string variable in ColdFusion that uses a single quote and two double quotes within the string?

```
MyVar = "Include multiple addresses on "Recipient's E-Mail" separated by commas.";
```

I know I could break this up into several variables or escape some characters, but I am wondering if there is a standard "best" way, one that is concise and easy to read.

I could do it this way, but this is cumbersome:

```
// THIS WORKS
MyVar = "Include multiple addresses on ";
MyVar = MyVar & '"Recipient's E-Mail "';
MyVar = MyVar & "separated by commas.";
```

I should have noted that I am using CFSCRIPT within a function. This makes using savecontent bulky. And CF didn't like the name of my var (LOCAL.Info[i].EmailProd07) in savecontent, so I had to rename it.

```
// THIS WORKS
savecontent variable="LOCAL.MyVar" {
writeOutput("Multiple recipients may be included in ""Recipient's E-Mail"" separated by commas.");
};
LOCAL.Info[i].EmailProd07 = LOCAL.MyVar;

// THIS WORKS
LOCAL.Info[i].EmailProd07 = 'Multiple recipients may be included in "Recipient''s E-Mail" separated by commas.';
```

Comment: Have you tried savecontent?

Comment: I have not tried savecontent.

Comment: (Edit) On second thought, I do not think savecontent is going to help you out here.

Comment: Not the script version anyway..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
MyVar = 'Include multiple addresses on "Recipient''s E-Mail" separated by commas.';
WriteOutput(MyVar);
```

The keys were:

1. Enclose string with single quotes to escape double quotes in the variable
2. Escape single quotes in variable with another single quote

**Edit starts here**

Here it is again, but with the single and double quotes switched.

```
MyVar = "Include multiple addresses on ""Recipient's E-Mail"" separated by commas.";
```

Works just as well

Comment: I like to be consistent in wrapping strings with double quotes, but your answer works perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to switch those around. I just want to touch the actual string content as little as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Which brings up the point of, from where does this string come and what do you do with it once you have it?

Answer (score 9):

[CF DOC](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7fd1.html):

> **Escaping quotation marks and number signs**
>
> To include a single-quotation character in a string that is
>   single-quoted, use two single-quotation marks (known as escaping the
>   single-quotation mark). The following example uses escaped
>   single-quotation marks:
>
> ```
> <cfset myString='This is a single-quotation mark: '' This is a double-quotation mark: "'> 
> <cfoutput>#mystring#</cfoutput><br>
> ```
>
> To include a double-quotation mark in a double-quoted string, use two
>   double-quotation marks (known as escaping the double-quotation mark).
>   The following example uses escaped double-quotation marks:
>
> ```
> <cfset myString="This is a single-quotation mark: ' This is a double-quotation mark: """> 
> <cfoutput>#mystring#</cfoutput><br>
> ```
>
> Because strings can be in either double-quotation marks or
>   single-quotation marks, both of the preceding examples display the
>   same text:
>
> ```
> This is a single-quotation mark: ' This is a double-quotation mark: "
> ```

---

I would add:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="MyVar">
  Include multiple addresses on "Recipient's E-Mail" separated by commas.
</cfsavecontent>
```

And if whitespace matters, either use `trim()` afterwards, or if the content is short, just keep the tag and content in one line with no whitespace in between.

Comment: I am writing in CFSCRIPT, so things are a little different.  I can get the savecontent to work, but the name is tough. (See above).

Comment: `<cfsavecontent>` only makes sense as a solution for your problem in CFML, not CFScript.

Comment: You can also use #chr(34)# for double quote and #chr(39)# for single quotes.

Comment: Another cfscript-friendly workaround would be saving the string into a file, and then `fileOpen()` & `fileRead()`, but why would anyone do that...

Comment: Or put the `<cfsavecontent>` in a separate .cfm and include that in your script-only file. I love script, but in some situations tags are just better.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use the CHR function? http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_c-d_04.html

This would mean you simply replace one set of "'s with the correct character code instead.

Answer (score -2):

you need to use the escape characters

usually it is : \

example :

string a = "bla bla bla \' dsfdsf \' bla "

Comment: So it works? I haven't tried it but I don't think this is documented.

Comment: I find that attempting to answer questions on forums like this is very educational.

Comment: No, it doesn't work in CFML. CFML doesn't have an escape character like that. As others have suggested, to escape either type of quote (single or double) within a string delimited with the same quote... double it up.  "double quote: """; 'single quote: '''

Comment: What happened when I tried it? *It didn't work*, obviously. Because it doesn't.